# Create object of appropriate subclass dynamically

Tags: python, oop, inheritance

How do i implement the following functionality?

I have 1 superclass "Vehicle" and 2 subclasses "Car" and "Airplane".

The superclass has all the shared attributes like "weight", "color" and "size".
The subclasses each have type-specific attributes. "engine_type" and "transmission" for cars. "Wing_length" and "wing_height" for airplanes.

The application goes through sale adverts of both car and airplanes and is supposed to create an object for each.

```
# Advert as string
ad = "For sale: my porsche. weight: 2000kg, black color, diesel engine, 6-gear transmission."

carforsale = Vehicle(ad)
```

How do i make it so that the "carforsale" object is of type Car(). Don't worry about the logic of parsing the advert, they come as structured json files.

I have read about "factory patterns". Are those what i want in this case?
Could anyone provide a simple python example of a solution for my problem?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Did you try `Car(ad)`? I'm not sure what the question is.

Comment: A simple `if` statement should suffice...

Comment: How do you determine that the advert is for a `Car` or an `Airplane`... use that logic in the factory pattern (e.g. `@staticmethod` on `Vehicle`).

Comment: well i just check how the json ad is structured. if theres a key "transmission" i know it's a car. So you're suggesting to use a factory pattern?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can use Factory Pattern for this. The Factory class will provide you an encapsulation for the logic how objects are being created. However, in Python you don't need a class, so the factory function `get_vehicle` will provide you a convenient way to get different vehicles based on the json you provide as argument to the function. Your example is quiet simple and what I am doing in the factory could be done in the base `Vehicle` class, but for more complex examples, it may be useful to encapsulate that logic in a separate Factory class or in a top-level function as in this example. The worst thing you could do is using bunch of `if/else` statements in several places (outside of the above mentioned classes), that decision what kind of object needs to be created should be in one single place. The reason is, that way you don't need to repeat yourself.

Here is a definition from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern):

> the factory method pattern is a creational pattern that uses factory
>   methods to deal with the problem of creating objects without having to
>   specify the exact class of the object that will be created. This is
>   done by creating objects by calling a factory method—either specified
>   in an interface and implemented by child classes, or implemented in a
>   base class and optionally overridden by derived classes—rather than by
>   calling a constructor.

Here is a simple code. If I understood your question correctly, you should use something like this.

```
class Vehicle:
    def __init__(self, json_obj):
        self.color = json_obj['color']


class Car(Vehicle):
    def __init__(self, json_obj):
        super(Car, self).__init__(json_obj)
        self.engine_type = json_obj['engine_type']

    def __repr__(self):
        return 'Car {} {}'.format(self.color, self.engine_type)


class Airplane(Vehicle):
    def __init__(self, json_obj):
        super(Airplane, self).__init__(json_obj)
        self.wing_length = json_obj['wing_length']


type_to_class = {'car': Car, 'airplane': Airplane}

def extract_type(json_obj):
    # decide how to get the type, replace the return statement with your logic
    return 'car'

def get_vehicle(json_obj):
    vehicle_type = extract_type(json_obj)
    return type_to_class[vehicle_type](json_obj)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    car = get_vehicle({'color': 'red', 'engine_type': 'v_type'})
    print(car)
```

UPDATE: Updated the code after reading @juanpa.arrivillaga suggestions. Using "top-level" function is the Pythonic way, so let's do it that way :) I have been using design patterns more intensively in purely Object Oriented languages, so it looked more natural to me to use a Factory class, but it's not really necessary, so let's have cleaner code.

Comment: A class with a single static method screams "this should just be a module-level function and not a class". Python != Java. Everything doesn't have to be a class definition.

Comment: Ok, he could add the method for the logic to get the type of the vehicle in that class. I'm not a fan of having many module-level functions. If I am using OOP, I prefer to encapsulate methods in classes.

Comment: Why? Again, Python != Java. If it makes you feel more comfortable, just think of it as a static class. A module is just another object anyway. Don't conflate " using OOP" with "writing class definitions"

Comment: I would not agree that having a class with a single static method is the Python way. Indeed, `staticmethod` was a relatively late addition to Python, and was mostly added because a bunch of Java/C++ people kept asking "how do you make a static method" and could accept the answer "you just want a module level function". The Pythonic way is to use a module level function. The one advantage to a staticmethod is that you can access already existing class attributes without having g to pass arguments, but that advantage is moot if you are making a totally separate class.

Comment: And that's exactly what I'm saying, `VehicleFactory` should just be a function. No need for this extra namespace. Python values clarity and simplicity over boilerplate code

Comment: I wasn't aware it's a new feature and always have used it as regularly as in the other languages. OK, maybe here a little bit less, because sometimes I use `@classmethod`. Thanks for the clarification, then I guess I should replace the class and use a function instead.

Comment: `classmethod` is actually quite handy because it gives you access to the class instance. But yeah, I urge you not to simply transliterate from Java style languages to Python. Free yourself. And for the love of Guido, don't write getters and setters!

Comment: Thank you all very much!

Comment: Just wanted to say, I like this implementation. Most of the "here's a factory pattern in Python" implementations look like all other languages, which for most of the code I write (even in other languages) always felt unnecessary.